# Notation of Euler's Totient Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, prime-numbers

this is a short question that can probably be answered quickly but I can't seem to find an it. I was browsing the Wikipedia page for Euler's Quotient Function and couldn't decipher this: $$\phi = n \prod_{\left. p\right| n}\left( 1-\dfrac{1}{p}\right)$$

I am unfamiliar with the notation '${\left. p\right| n}$'. As a programmer, my mind immediately went to the bitwise OR operator but I doubt it has any connection. What does this notation mean? Thanks for any help!

Comment: $p|n$ is read as $p$ divides $n$.

Comment: There is a lot hiding in that formula. $p\mid n$ just mean $p$ divides $n,$ or $n$ is a multiple of $p.$ But the $p$ variable is sort of hidden notion - it means it is the product over all prime factor values of $n.$ If the notation was $$\prod_{d\mid n}$$ then it would mean the product over all (positive) divisors $d$ of $n.$

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to MSE!

As is mentioned in the comments, we say $p \mid n$ to mean "$p$ divides $n$", and by convention when we use $p$ in number theory it's assumed we're only considering primes. So the equation

$$\varphi(n) = n \prod_{p \mid n} \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right )$$

reads

"$\varphi(n)$ is the product of $n$ with $1 - \frac{1}{p}$ for all the prime divisors of $n$"

This is probably best clarified with an example. Let's look at, say, $12$. The primes dividing $12$ are $2$ and $3$, so the formula predicts that

$$\varphi(12) = 12 \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{2} \right ) \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{3} \right ) = 4$$

and indeed you can check that $\varphi(12)$ is actually $4$, since $1,5,7,11$ are all the numbers below and coprime to $12$.

As a quick warning, notice we only count $2$ once, even though $2^2 \mid 12$. I've had some students make this mistake in the past.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: That explains it perfectly thanks so much!

Comment: Happy to help ^_^. If this answered your question you should mark it as such by clicking the green checkmark icon. This way other users of the site know where to spend their time